# C# DateTime to Int and RadCalendar

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to parse out a RadCalendar Date and disable the dates prior to our Start Date of an event.

We get our StartDateTime from a database and I would like to disable the dates from our Future StartDateTime all the way back to the beginning of the current (this) month.

### EDIT:  More specific

### Example: My StartDateTime is in November 2014 but I want to disable all dates from that future date until back to the beginning of this current month (this month is August 2014).

Below is the code we currently have, but it is only looking back i < 31. This is why I would like to the DateTime get the number of days as an int all the way back to the beginning (the 1st) of the current month.

```
 if (nextAvailableTime != null && nextAvailableTime.StartDateTime > DateTime.Today)
        {
            //DISABLE dates prior to next available date
            DateTime dt = nextAvailableTime.StartDateTime.AddDays(-1);
            for (var i = 0; i < 31; i++) //Would like to change this to beginning of current month.
            {
                tkCalendar.SpecialDays.Add(new RadCalendarDay(tkCalendar) { Date = dt.Date.AddDays(i * -1), IsDisabled = true, IsSelectable = false });
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why not use DateTime.DayOfYear and subtract current DayOfYear from future DayOfYear to get what i should increment to?

Answer (score 2):

Why not subtract the 2 dates and get the difference in days? I used my own variable because I was unclear what your variables were. My loop is disabling going forward instead of multiplying by -1. You may need to edit the loop to be <= or start from 1 depending on if you want the first and last date to be included.

```
if (nextAvailableTime != null && nextAvailableTime.StartDateTime > DateTime.Today)
  {
        //DISABLE dates prior to next available date
        DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime futureDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3);
        int daysBetween = (futureDate - currentDate).Days;
        for (var i = 0; i <  daysBetween; i++) 
        {
            tkCalendar.SpecialDays.Add(new RadCalendarDay(tkCalendar) { Date =  currentDate.AddDays(i), IsDisabled = true, IsSelectable = false });
        }
   }
```

Comment: That's not quite what I was looking for.  I updated my question to be more specific.  It is actually doing the same thing.

Comment: I revised my answer, let me know if I misunderstood/

Comment: That is more or less what I needed. But this thing is, we never really know what the future date is going to be, it could be 3 months out it could be 6 months out, it could be 1 month out. A more dynamic solution is better. I did see Pete's suggestion above, this is what you are more or less doing, but in a more static way by setting the (3). But this is the right track for me.

Comment: I only added three months for a test variable so you could see the concept. I have no idea how you are getting the future date but any date will work in place of `futureDate` in my code.

Answer (score 0):

The answer we came up with was to get the next available date and then the beginning date of the current month and get the difference using DayOfYear.

Solution is below:

```
  if (nextAvailableTime != null && nextAvailableTime.StartDateTime > DateTime.Today)
        {

       //DISABLE dates prior to next available date
           DateTime dt = nextAvailableTime.StartDateTime.AddDays(-1);
           DateTime nextDate = nextAvailableTime.StartDateTime;
        //Gate the calendar to just go get the product's next available date and then get block out everything until the beginning of the current month.
            var now = DateTime.Now;
            var startOfMonth = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1);

          TimeSpan daysBetween = (futureDate - startOfMonth);
           //  for (var i = 0; i < 31; i++)//Original from 31 days from next available.
            for (var i = 0; i < daysBetween.Days; i++) //Get difference between next available and beginning of current month.
                {
                   tkCalendar.SpecialDays.Add(new RadCalendarDay(tkCalendar) { Date = dt.Date.AddDays(i * -1), IsDisabled = true, IsSelectable = false });
                }
        }
```

Comment: This code will not work if the future date is in the next calendar year (`daysBetween` will be negative). You should just subtract the dates and get the result in days like I showed in my answer.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I updated the code to a better solution using Days and TimeSpan instead.  Thanks for catching that. Saved me lots of future frustration.

Comment: I see your updated code, looks like you took the same approach as my answer. Glad to help.